# How to make concentric color blocks with css?

Tags: html, css

I tried to make several embedded color blocks concentric using the following code:

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px
}
#div1 {
  background: yellow;
}
#div2 {
  background: orange;
  padding: 50px;
}
#div3 {
  background: red;
  padding: 100px;
}
#div4 {
  background: purple;
  padding: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div4">
  <div id="div3">
    <div id="div2">
      <div id="div1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, this is what I get:
[image]

The div1 and div2 blocks embed concentrically as expected, but the other two outer blocks seem to collapse on the paddings. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to set the `width` and `height` for the innermost element. The rest can be sized with `padding`. Put `display: inline-block` on the outermost element to keep it from stretching, or set its `width` to `500px`.

```css
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}
#div2 {
  background: orange;
  padding: 50px;
}
#div3 {
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
}
#div4 {
  background: purple;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div4">
  <div id="div3">
    <div id="div2">
      <div id="div1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
#div1 {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: yellow;
margin: auto;
}
#div2 {
background: orange;
padding: 50px;
}
#div3 {
background: red;
padding: 50px;
}
#div4 {
background: purple;
padding: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</html>
```